# How to hide selected fields from all templates in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

Please suggest me..

I want to hide "modifieduser_id" field from all template..

Is there any way to hide this field from Controllers.

```
<div class="masterroles form large-10 medium-9 columns">
<?= $this->Form->create($masterrole) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Masterrole') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
       echo $this->Form->input('modifieduser_id');
  ?>
</fieldset>
<?php  //$this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: use input type hidden .. echo $this->Form->input('modifieduser_id',['type'=>'hidden']);

Comment: It is correct. but we have to implement it in each template page. I want to avoid it. i will have to set on global level..

Comment: put the id in session variable then

Comment: why you don't put it on controller, when you save the data! or you can also use http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators

Comment: To hide "modifieduser_id" text box, i have to modify each template.. therefore i am think is there any way to hide "modifieduser_id" text box from any one location in that case it will reflect in all templates..